# Lazarus open XML file in TMemo

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal

I'm trying to open an XML file in a TMemo as text. Everytime I do this is what it opens:

[image]

I know that's not what's in the XML, if I open that file in Notepad it opens fine and shows XML data, plain text.

This is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ss: string;
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  ss := '';
  runcommand('msinfo32 /nfo pcinfo.xml', ss);
  sl:=TStringList.Create;
  sl.LoadFromFile('pcinfo.xml');
  Memo2.Text := sl.Text;
  sl.Free;
end;
```

Comment: That's probably an [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) marker at the beginning. Can you specify the encoding of the file?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Notepad > Save As > Encoding > UTF-8. I guess @a_horse_with_no_name is only halfway right: BOM sure, but not UTF-8. More likely one of UTF-16. If your XML contains nothing but ASCII you can also encode it as ANSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file was saved in Unicode, opening Notepad and Save As the file showed me encoding. So opening the file into a stream, then converting to UTF8 worked like a charm.

```
stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    stream.LoadFromFile('pcinfo.xml');
    SetLength(s, stream.Size);
    stream.ReadBuffer(s[1], stream.Size);
    memo2.Text := ConvertEncoding(s, GuessEncoding(s), EncodingUTF8);
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
```